# Print data horizontally in FastReport

Tags: c#, matrix, fastreport

In Winform and C#, How can I show data in dataset in FastReport horizontally?

Example:

```
1     2     3     4    5    ...
```

Finally I want to show data in Matrix format with specific count of column.

Example:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

My effort:

1. Adding the `FastReport.TextObject` controls manually.

   in this case I can't find out when I pass the page.
2. Using the `Table` control. But I have just one column in database and I can't handle this.

Answer (score 2):

See FastReport Demo 【Table>Column DataSource】

Demo Download Link： https://【fast-report url】/en/download/fast-report-net/

```
private void Table1_ManualBuild(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // get the data source by its name
  DataSourceBase columnData = Report.GetDataSource("Employees");
  // init the data source
  columnData.Init();

  // print the first table column - it is a header
  Table1.PrintColumn(0);
  // each PrintColumn call must be followed by either PrintRow or PrintRows call
  // to print cells on the column
  Table1.PrintRows();

  // now enumerate the data source and print the table body
  while (columnData.HasMoreRows)
  {
    // print the table body  
    Table1.PrintColumn(1);
    Table1.PrintRows();

    // go next data source row
    columnData.Next();
  }

  // print the last table column - it is a footer
  Table1.PrintColumn(2);
  Table1.PrintRows();
}
```

Comment: So, there is no a direct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Using Table ManualBuild Event, you can show data horizontally,like this:

(I can't upload the .frx, so you can download the fast-report demo and view details)

[image: Using Table ManualBuild Event, you can show data horizontally,like this:]

```
private void Table1_ManualBuild(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // get the data source by its name
  DataSourceBase columnData = Report.GetDataSource("Employees");
  // init the data source
  columnData.Init();

  // print the first table column - it is a header
  Table1.PrintColumn(0);
  // each PrintColumn call must be followed by either PrintRow or PrintRows call
  // to print cells on the column
  Table1.PrintRows();

  // now enumerate the data source and print the table body
  while (columnData.HasMoreRows)
  {
    // print the table body  
    Table1.PrintColumn(1);
    Table1.PrintRows();

    // go next data source row
    columnData.Next();
  }

  // print the last table column - it is a footer
  Table1.PrintColumn(2);
  Table1.PrintRows();
}
```